# Ipywidget Accordion default behaviour

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

**Ipywidget accordion** is expanded by default when the notebook is executed for the first time. How to make the accordion collapsed by default ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set `selected_index = None` when creating the Accordion.

```py
from ipywidgets import Accordion, FloatSlider
acc = Accordion(children=[FloatSlider()], selected_index=None)
display(acc)
```

[image]